# jquery dialog box does not close when clicks on X icon on the first attempt in IE

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

In IE browser,on click on title bar/close icon dialog is getting resized and after this when clicks on close icon,close event get fired. Code is working in FF and chrome.I am using jquery UI v1.10.4

```
  $('#dialogBox').dialog({
                title: title,
                width: 'auto',
                position: "center",
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                open: function (args) {
                    $(this).parent().zIndex(50);
                    $(document).find(".ui-widget-overlay.ui-front").last().zIndex(40);
                },
                buttons: {
                    OK: {
                        text: "OK",
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-check"
                        },
                        "class": "dialog-button",
                        click: function () {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                           // do something
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-close"
                        },
                        "class": "dialog-button",
                        click: function () {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                   $(this).dialog("close");
                }
         });
```

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: IE 9,10 and IE11. But working on IE8